# MathID changes after reboot on Linux

Tags: bugs, version-10, linux

I recently installed Mathematica 10.3 on Arch Linux. I activated my license, and all seemed to be well, but when I reboot my computer, the MathID changes, and it shows that the software is not activated, so I activate again. I repeated this process about 5 times now, requesting a system transfer for my activation key, but it just keeps changing. 
What's weird is that it doesn't happen after every reboot. Sometimes I reboot, and it's still the same. Other times, it goes back to a previously activated MathID and I can use the software, after it had changed to another one on a previous boot. 
Anyone has any idea how to deal with this issue?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Does a reboot potentially change the hardware that is available to the system?

Comment: Are you installing new drivers for anything? Do you have any... strange peripherals devices attached to your computer? Any chance it switches back and forth between multiple MathIDs?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I would contact Wolfram Technical Support about:  http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical

Comment: @user21 No, it doesn't. Nothing changes. All hardware is the same.

Comment: @Searke No drivers change either. No strange peripherals, nothing. All logs are the same after a reboot, but the MathID changes.
It does switch back and forth though. It is currently on an activated one right now. It wasn't my last boot.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same problem under Manjaro (Arch Linux derivate) and Mathematica 11 and thought it was due to the new Network Manager 1.4 automatically randomizing the WiFi MAC Address. But you had the problem before MAC Address Randomization was introduced...

Comment: I also have the very same problem. I'm using Arch. Did someone solve the it?

Comment: @MaPo MAC address changing sounds like the most likely candidate to me. This (unique) address is traditionally hard-coded into the network adapter, and so has come to be used as a sort of ID for the computer by a lot of software. But some network drivers let the MAC address be changed at will, or even change it randomly, which can pose problems. The reason to change it randomly is to defeat surveillance tactics that look for connections to wireless networks by certain MAC addresses as a way to track a person's movements.

Answer (score 1):

It’s perhaps the WiFi-connection. On a Toshiba KIRA-107 (8 GiB RAM) with Debian-Knoppix the MathID stays stable, even between boots, when the WiFi-card is on and connected to the same wireless network. Don’t know if this helps.